# How to name a Matlab output file using input from a text file

Tags: file, matlab, text

I am trying to take an input from a text file in this format:

```
Processed_kplr010074716-2009131105131_llc.fits.txt
Processed_kplr010074716-2009166043257_llc.fits.txt
Processed_kplr010074716-2009259160929_llc.fits.txt
etc.... (there are several hundred lines)
```

and use that input to name my output files for a Matlab loop. Each time the loop ends, i would like it to process the results and save them to a file such as:

```
Matlab_Processed_kplr010074716-2009131105131_llc.fits.txt
```

This would make identifying the object which has been processed easier as I can then just look for the ID number and not of to sort through a list of random saved filenames. I also need it to save plots that are generated in each loop in a similar fashion.
This is what I have so far:

```
fileNames = fopen('file_list_1.txt', 'rt');
inText = textscan(fileNames, '%s');
outText = [inText]';
fclose(fileNames)

for j:numel(Data)
%Do Stuff
save(strcat('Matlab_',outText(j),'.txt'))
print(Plot, '-djpeg', strcat(outText(j),'.txt'))
end
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: So what exactly is your error/problem?

Comment: As a side not, dont need to use strcat, its enough to use brackets to concatenate strings, e.g. `[outText(j), '.txt']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `save` command to save to a text file, you need to use `-ascii` tab, see the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/save.html) for more details. You might also want to use `dlmwrite` instead(or even `fprintf`, but I don't believe you can write the whole matrix at once with `fprintf`, you have to loop over the rows).